# installing phonegap on windows7 error

Tags: apache, ant, cordova

I am a web developer and new to Phonegap..

I was trying to install phone gap on my windows 7 machine as per described here

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface

but when i run the following command

```
cordova platform add android
```

i am getting the following error

```
[Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project.
ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and added to y
our path.
]
```

does this mean that i should install apache ant on my machine ? if so can someone redirect me to right link.

I am also running wampserver on my machine for my other developments..

will installing 'ant' affect on my wamp ?

Answer (score 3):

As described in [PhoneGap Getting Started](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html)

> Finally, you may need to include %ANT_HOME%\bin to your PATH as well. To check to see if this is required, run a command prompt and type ant. If the program can not be found add %ANT_HOME%\bin to the PATH. You may need to specify the full path instead of using the %ANT_HOME% environment variable.

If you need ant for Windows, you may want to download and install it from [here](https://code.google.com/p/winant/)

Answer (score 1):

You need ant to add the android platform.
Ant is a java-based build tool.

You can get further informations and download it at http://ant.apache.org.

ant has nothing to do with the apache webserver and doesn't effect your wamp installation. It's another software product provided by the apache foundation.

lg

fastrde